# Request number generation - ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to make a small request management application, and I need to generate a request number for each request.

The request number should be in this format: R00000001, followed by R00000002, and so on. Below is the code i have written.

```
If oRs.EOF Then
    txtTransID="R"&"00000001"
else 
    segments=Split(oRs.Fields("REQ_ID"),"R")
    txtTransID=segments(1)+1
end if
```

The first request gets generated correctly, but the next request will just return R2. I need to have zeros before the number, the second request number should become R00000002.

Kindly advise how this can be done. If there is any other way to do this, that is also fine. I am using VB as the language.

i have tried using toString function, but it does not seem to work as i am using VB as my language. Kindly help something that i can do with VB

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
txtTransID="R" & i.ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"c)
```

**Edit:**

You need to declare i as your new Request number.

Here sample code.

```
   Public Class oRs
        Public Shared EOF As Boolean = False
        Public Shared Fields As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    End Class


    Protected Overrides Sub Test()
        oRs.Fields.Add("REQ_ID", "R00000001")
        Dim txtTransID As String = Nothing


        ' Your code starts here '
        If oRs.EOF Then
            txtTransID = "R" & "00000001"
        Else
            Dim strOldRequest As String = System.Convert.ToString(oRs.Fields("REQ_ID"))
            Dim iOldRequest As Integer = Int32.Parse(strOldRequest.Split("R"c)(1))
            iOldRequest += 1
            txtTransID = "R" & iOldRequest.ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"c)
        End If

    End Sub
```

If your classic ASP does not declare `Int32.Parse`, try `CInt(YOUR_STRING)`,  if it doesn't support `object.ToString` try `CStr(YOUR_Number)` and if you don't have `PadLeft`, add it as normal function:

```
Function Rpad (sValue, sPadchar, iLength)
  Rpad = sValue & string(iLength - Len(sValue), sPadchar)
End Function

Function Lpad (sValue, sPadchar, iLength)
  Lpad = string(iLength - Len(sValue),sPadchar) & sValue
End Function
```

On a sidenote, why don't you just save the old request number as integer instead of string ?

```
"R" & (iOldNr + 1).ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"c)
```

Keep the data and it's presentation separate.

If you still need it with R0000xy in a datatable, you can always do a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
    'R' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(REQ_ID AS varchar(20)), 8) AS RequestNr 
FROM T_Requests
```

And on another sidenote, you don't really need any of your code, your problem is so simple, you can even do it entirely in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    'R' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ISNULL(MAX(REQ_ID), 0) + 1 AS varchar(20)), 8) AS NextRequestNr 
FROM T_Requests
```

Comment: I get below error. Can you advise what is "i". Should i create an object for this?

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required: 'i'

Comment: Well, you need to define i, which is the number you want displayed. Like "Dim i As Integer = 5"

Comment: Joel fixed the mis-tag - He's working in VBScript not VB.Net, which doesn't quite work like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a generic function:

```vbs
Function GetNextValue(rawValue, numOfLetters)
    Dim strNumericPart, result
    If Len(rawValue)<=numOfLetters Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 10000, "Illegal value: '" & rawValue & "', must have at least " &_
            (numOfLetters + 1) & " characters"
        Exit Function
    End If
    strNumericPart = Right(rawValue, Len(rawValue) - numOfLetters)
    If Not(IsNumeric(strNumericPart)) Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 10001, "Illegal value: '" & rawValue & "', last " &_
            (Len(rawValue) - numOfLetters) & " characters must be numeric"
        Exit Function
    End If
    result = (CLng(strNumericPart) + 1) & ""
    Do Until Len(result)=Len(strNumericPart)
        result = "0" & result
    Loop
    result = Left(rawValue, numOfLetters) & result
    GetNextValue = result
End Function
```

This will generate the desired value by string manipulation. Usage example:

```
segments = oRs("REQ_ID")
txtTransID = GetNextValue(segments, 1)
```

The first argument is the raw value (e.g. `R00000001`) and the second is how many letters you have in the beginning so the function can parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it looks like you're just missing the 0 padding. You want to write a padded number out like so I believe.

```
Dim txtTransID, segments, incrementedNumber, paddedNumber
If oRs.EOF Then
    txtTransID="R00000001"
Else 
    segments=Split(oRs.Fields("REQ_ID"),"R")
    incrementedNumber = segments(1)+1
    paddedNumber = Right(String(8,"0") & incrementedNumber, 8) 
    txtTransID = "R" & paddedNumber
End If
```